# A set of positive measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, ideals, filters

There are 2 notions used as a definition of a **positive measure** of a set:

A set $A\subseteq \kappa$ is positive, with respect to a filter $F$ on $\kappa$, if intersects every element of $F$.

For the second, let $I$ be the dual ideal for the filter $F$.

Then $B$ is positive if $B\notin I$ (see the snippet below). Are these two notions (easily) equivalent ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two notions are equivalent.

Suppose first that a set $A$ intersects every element of $F$. Then $A$ is not the complement of any element of $F$, so $A \notin I$. Thus, $A$ has positive measure with respect to the second definition.

On the other hand, suppose $B \notin I$. In particular, this means that $B^{c} \notin F$. Given $X \in F$, if $B \cap X = \emptyset$, then $X \subseteq B^{c}$. But filters are upward-closed, so $B^{c} \in F$, contradiction. Hence $B$ intersects every element of $F$, so $B$ has positive measure with respect to the first definition.